# Cakephp save request data according

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

My issue here,is about  how can i save my data that was requested on a form into two tables and knowing the user_id that i will be generated.
These tables are linked but there are one field(id) on the first table(users) that is automaticaly generated(sequencial number) and i will need that value to insert on the second table(address).

```
For example:
In my view.ctp:
     -- Users
                        <div>Name</div>
                        <div><?php echo $this->Form2->input('name'); ?></div>
                        <div>Surname</div>
                        <div><?php echo $this->Form2->input('surname'); ?></div>
    -- Contacts
                        <div>Phone</div>
                        <div><?php echo $this->Form2->input('phone'); ?></div>
                        <div>Address</div>
                        <div><?php echo $this->Form2->input('address'); ?></div>
```

This is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(50),
    surname varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contactos (
  id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int(10) NOT NULL,
  tipo enum('Entrega', 'Facturação'),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id));
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your `model's` are associated then this will automatic saves associated model data-

```
<div>Name</div>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->input('name'); ?></div>
<div>Surname</div>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->input('surname'); ?></div>

<div>Phone</div>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.phone'); ?></div>
<div>Address</div>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.address'); ?></div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Save');
```

Answer (score 0):

**View:**

```
   <div>Name</div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
    <div><?php echo $this->Form->input('name'); ?></div>
    <div>Surname</div>
    <div><?php echo $this->Form->input('surname'); ?></div>        
    <div>Phone</div>
    <div><?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.phone'); ?></div>
    <div>Address</div>
    <div><?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.address'); ?></div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end('Save');
```

**Controller:**

```
  $this->User->Contact->saveAll($this->request->data); // TO save ABOVE FORM DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I understand your problem.You can do it by like this also . First insert values in first table `User`  like this

```
  $data = array();
  $data['name'] = $this->request->data('name');
  $data['surname'] = $this->request->data('surname');
  $this->User->save($data);
```

and then get the last inserted user id like this

```
$id = $this->User->getInsertID();
```

and now insert in another table

```
 $contactdata = array();
  $contactdata['user_id'] = $id;
 $contactdata['phone'] = $this->request->data('Contact.phone');
  $contactdata['address'] = $this->request->data('Contact.address');

  $this->Contact->save( $contactdata);
```

This is an alternative way.